# Limit on api graph explorer call not working as I want

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-requests

I'm trying this [call](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3DGoogle%2CDrumTalkTv%26fields%3Dposts.limit(1)%7Bmessage%7D&version=v2.12) on Api Graph explorer.

`?ids=Google,DrumTalkTv&fields=posts.limit(1){message}`

And I get a post from Google and another from DrumtalkTV but I want limit the call to just 1 post, not 2.

How can I limit the total amount of posts when I retrieve posts from several pages?

Comment: No that is not possible